# Regex capturando tudo

Tags: html, regex

Estou com problemas com uma Regex, ela não está a pegar apenas `1 de 8` como eu desejo, ela está pegando muito além disto, veja : https://www.regex101.com/r/eX6bC9/1

Essa é a string que estou tentando combinar:

```
<span class='pages'>1 de 8</span><span class='current'>1</span><a class="page larger" href="http://megafilmeshd.net/category/lancamentos/page/2/">2</a><a class="page larger" href="http://megafilmeshd.net/category/lancamentos/page/3/">3</a><span class='extend'>...</span>
```

E a regex:

```
<span class='pages'>(.*)<\/span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para capturar apenas

```
<span class='pages'>1 de 8</span>
```

Adicione uma interrogação na regex, ela significa que o grupo conteúdo dentro do parentesses vai combinar apenas uma vez, ela 'anula' o combinar tudo o maximo possível (`.*`)

```
<span class='pages'>(.*?)<\/span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema é que o quantificador `*` é **guloso**, o que significa que ele vai casar o máximo da entrada que for possível antes de desistir. Se você quer que ele case o mínimo possível, pode usar seu variante preguiçoso, o `*?`:

```
<span class='pages'>(.*?)<\/span>
```

Dito isso, pense duas vezes antes de usar expressões regulares para interpretar HTML. Em alguns casos *muito* limitados pode até servir, mas em geral é melhor usar um *parser* completo para essa linguagem.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando as outras respostas, existe um *corner case* na solução proposta por elas. Se o HTML tiver um `span` comentado dentro do `span` que você quer pegar:

```html
<span class='pages'>1 de <!-- <span> comentado </span> --> 8</span><span class='current'>1</span>
```

A regex `<span class='pages'>(.*?)</span>` vai pegar o trecho:

```html
<span class='pages'>1 de <!-- <span> comentado </span>
```

Deixando de fora o fechamento do comentário (`-->`), o `8` e o fechamento da tag (`</span>`) - [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/y3Anai/2/).

Isso acontece porque o [quantificador *lazy*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) ("preguiçoso") `*?` [pega a menor quantidade possível de caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052).

Ou seja, a regex primeiro pega `<span class='pages'>`, e depois pega a menor quantidade possível de caracteres que tenha um `</span>` depois. Por isso a regex só vai até o `</span>` que está dentro dos comentários.

---

É por casos assim que dizem que [regex não é a melhor ferramenta para fazer *parsing* de HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Para o caso acima, por exemplo, qualquer *parser* de HTML (que a grande maioria das linguagens de programação possui) consegue resolver facilmente, pois eles já conseguem analisar a estrutura do HTML e os comentários podem ser facilmente ignorados. Já com regex, você teria que incluir na expressão um trecho para detectar comentários ([que não é tão simples assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29194283)), ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
<span class='pages'>((?:[^<>]*|(?=<!--).*?-->)*)</span>
```

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/y3Anai/4) esta regex funcionando.

Agora, em vez de simplesmente `.*?`, há duas alternativas (separadas pelo `|`, [que significa **ou**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)):

1. `[^<>]`: é uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). No caso, é "qualquer caractere que **não** seja `<` nem `>`". Isso garante que não ultrapassaremos o fechamento da tag, evitando que a regex "invada" outros `span`'s.
2. `(?=<!--).*?-->`:

   - primeiro temos um [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (o trecho `(?=<!--)`), que verifica se algo existe à frente. No caso, ele verifica se temos uma abertura de comentário (`<!--`)
   - depois temos `.*?` (zero ou mais caracteres), com o quantificador *lazy* para que ele não invada outros comentários (da mesma forma que a solução original usa `.*?` para evitar que a regex invada outras tags `span`)
   - seguido do fechamento de comentário `-->`

Toda a alternância possui o quantificador `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências), então é basicamente `((?:opção 1|opção 2)*)`. Ou seja, dentro da tag `span` eu posso ter vários caracteres que não são `<` nem `>`, ou vários comentários. Eu uso `(?:` para que os parênteses internos [não formem um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (caso contrário, o conteúdo do mesmo seria capturado em um grupo à parte).

---

Mas isso ainda não resolve todos os casos. Se o `span` tiver outra tag dentro dele:

```html
<span class='pages'>1 de <!-- <span> comentado </span> --> <a href="www.google.com">link</a> 8</span><span class='current'>1</span>
```

A regex anterior não resolve, já que eu usei `[^<>]` para que ele não invadisse outras tags, e por isso a regex falha porque dentro do `span` tem a tag `<a>`. Então eu teria que mudar para algo do tipo:

```
<span class='pages'>((?:[^<>]*|(?=<!--).*?-->|<((?!span\b)[^> ]+)[^>]*>.*?</\2>)*)</span>
```

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/y3Anai/5/) esta regex funcionando.

Eu adicionei mais uma opção na alternância: `<((?!span\b)[^> ]+)[^>]*>.*?</\2>`. Basicamente, ela pega qualquer *tag* que não seja `span`, mas de maneira bem "genérica", já que ela não valida muita coisa. Para o nome da tag, por exemplo, eu usei `[^> ]` (qualquer coisa que não seja `>` nem espaço), o que quer dizer que se tiver tags como `<123.-*()x>`, a regex vai aceitar ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/y3Anai/6/)). Claro que você pode melhorá-la para que ela aceite somente nomes de tags válidos, mas olhe novamente para a regex: ela já está complicada o suficiente, e ainda sim não cobre todos os casos possíveis de HTML's válidos. Será que vale a pena continuar?

É claro que, para poucos casos mais simples, pequenos trechos de HTML, e entradas controladas, nas quais você "sabe" que não terá casos como os citados acima, uma regex mais simples - como a que as outras respostas sugeriram - pode resolver. Mas complique um pouco mais o HTML e já começa a ficar inviável. Para esses casos, um *parser* específico é o mais indicado.