# Expressões Regulares: função do quantificador lazy "?"

Tags: regex

Tenho aprendido sobre o uso de Expressões Regulares e li algumas explicações sobre o uso do sinal `?` (chamado *lazy quantifier*), como **[nesta documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)**:

> ***?** : Corresponde ao elemento anterior zero vezes ou mais, mas o menor número de vezes possível.

No RegExr me mostra a seguinte explicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu usar tanto a expressão `^(.*)$` quanto `^(.*?)$` ou `^(.+?)$` eu consigo o mesmo resultado:

```js
var string = "abcdef";
var re1 = /^(.*)$/;
var re2 = /^(.*?)$/;
var re3 = /^(.+?)$/;
console.log(string.match(re1));
console.log(string.match(re2));
console.log(string.match(re3));
```

O que não me ficou muito claro foi "*...mas o menor número de vezes possível.*".

**Como assim, *o menor número de vezes possível*?**

Em que situação se deve usar e quando não usar o `?` para quantificar o `*` ou o `+`, já que, como nos exemplos acima, usando ou não, o resultado é o mesmo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você obtem o mesmo resultado porque o `$` força que o fim do grupo de captura seja no fim da string. Assim, o menor número possível de vezes ainda vai necessariamente até o final da string.

O `?` pega o `*` ou `+` o menor número possível de vezes, em contraste com o default de regex que é ser "greedy", quer dizer, pegar o maior número possível de caracteres que se encaixam no padrão. Considere o seguinte:

```
var string = 'Eu quero pegar uma palavra que comece com "q" seguida por um espaço.';
var re1 = /(q.*) /;
console.log(string.match(re1)); 
// "quero pegar uma palavra que comece com \"q\" seguida por um"
```

Perceba que ao invés de pegar só o "quero", o grupo de captura pegou o `quero`, que começa com "q", *e mais tudo até o último espaço encontrado*. Por isso o regex é ganancioso: ele pega tudo o que consegue.

Vejamos agora a mesma coisa com o `?` que tira a ganância do regex:

```
var string = 'Eu quero pegar uma palavra que comece com "q" seguida por um espaço.';
var re2 = /(q.*?) /;
console.log(string.match(re2));
// "quero"
```

Isso está mais em linha com o que queríamos. O regex pegou no grupo de captura a minha palavra que começa com "q", *e parou no primeiro espaço*; quer dizer, ele deu match no menor número de caracteres possível que satisfaz a expressão regular.

No seu exemplo original, o menor número possível de caracteres ainda era a string completa porque com o `^` e o `$`, você forçava o regex a começar no primeiro caractere da string e terminar no último. Assim, a menor string que satisfaz a expressão completa é a string toda.

Comment: Boa explicação, mas testando no RegExr ele está selecionando tudo que começa com "q" até o primeiro espaço: https://regexr.com/3r7lk

Comment: Ah tah, foi por causa da flag `g`.

Comment: @dvd não por causa do flag `g`; é porque geralmente os engines de regex disponibilizam dois resultados: o match todo, ou só o que está no grupo de captura. O espaço, no caso desses regexes, está fora do grupo de captura, então o que comentei foi o resultado dos grupos de captura. Se rodar no console do navegador, vai ver que o resultado na verdade é um array com os dois valores (com e sem espaço).

Comment: Lá no RegExr desmarquei a flag global e só capturou o "quero"

Comment: @dvd engraçado. O [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GTRMQ8/1) mostra os grupos e full matches separados.

Comment: Pois eh, parece que os dois sites mostram de forma diferente os resultados.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine que você tenha uma página HTML gigante numa string `s` e você pesquise a regex `/<[^>]+>.*<\/[^>]+>/`. O que você vai obter? Sim, a tag html, todo o resto do documento e o fecha html, porque os quantificadores normais são *gulosos*.

Agora, se você tiver a mesma string `s` e uma regex `/<[^>]+>.*?<\/[^>]+>/`, o que você vai obter? Qualquer tag que abre e feche nos primeiros trechos do documento.

```js
$(function () {

  var s = $('#conteudo').html();
  
  alert('Original: ' + s);
  alert('Eager: ' + s.match(/<[^>]+>.*<\/[^>]+>/gm)[0]);
  alert('Lazy: ' + s.match(/<[^>]+>.*?<\/[^>]+>/gm)[0]);

});
```

```css
* { font-family: Consolas; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='conteudo'><table><thead><tr><th>Produto</th><th>Preço</th><th>Quantidade</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Feijão</td><td>R$ 8,75</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Arroz</td><td>R$ 4,99</td><td>2</td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><td>Total</td><td></td><td>R$ 18,73</td></tr></tfoot></table></div>
```

Comment: Pois eh, ainda estou nos primeiros passos de regex, mas já aprendi bastante coisa. Só fiquei com essa dúvida. ObG!

Comment: Eu acho este site bem bom: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 4):

Complementando as outras respostas, o `?` como indicador de [*lazyness*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) não se limita a ser usado apenas com `*` e `+`. Ele pode ser usado com qualquer outro [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), como o `{}`, por exemplo.

```js
let s = 'a1234567890';

// sem lazy, pega a maior quantidade possível
console.log(s.match(/a\d*/)); // a1234567890
console.log(s.match(/a\d+/)); // a1234567890
console.log(s.match(/a\d{3,7}/)); // a1234567
console.log(s.match(/a\d{3,}/)); // a1234567890
```

As expressões acima correspondem a uma letra `a` seguida de determinada quantidade de dígitos (`\d` seguido de um quantificador).

Nos casos acima não há o `?`, então os quantificadores estão no seu modo *default*, que é ser ["ganancioso" (*greedy*)](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap), ou seja, eles tentam pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres que satisfaça a expressão. Para `*` e `+`, não há um limite máximo (o `*` corresponde a zero ou mais ocorrências, e o `+` corresponde a uma ou mais ocorrências), então a "maior quantidade possível que satisfaz a expressão" corresponde a "todos os dígitos" (`1234567890`).

Já `\d{3,7}` significa "no mínimo 3, no máximo 7 dígitos", então a maior quantidade possível que satisfaz a expressão é 7, por isso o resultado é `a1234567`. E `\d{3,}` significa "no mínimo 3 dígitos, sem limite máximo", então a maior quantidade possível que satisfaz a expressão é "pegar todos os dígitos", por isso o resultado é `a1234567890`.

---

Agora se mudarmos todos esses quantificadores para o seu modo *lazy*:

```js
let s = 'a1234567890';

// com lazy, pega a menor quantidade possível
console.log(s.match(/a\d*?/)); // a
console.log(s.match(/a\d+?/)); // a1
console.log(s.match(/a\d{3,7}?/)); // a123
console.log(s.match(/a\d{3,}?/)); // a123
```

Agora, graças ao `?` logo depois, os quantificadores se tornam ["preguiçosos" (*lazy*)](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution), e passam a pegar a **menor** quantidade possível de caracteres que satisfaçam a expressão.

Como `*` significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências", a menor quantidade de dígitos que satisfaz a expressão é zero. Por isso o resultado do *match* é `a`.

Já o `+` significa "**uma** ou mais ocorrências", então a menor quantidade de dígitos que satisfaz a expressão é um. Por isso o resultado é `a1`.

Por fim, `{3,7}` significa "no mínimo 3, no máximo 7 ocorrências" e `{3,}` significa "no mínimo 3 ocorrências, sem limite máximo", então para ambos a menor quantidade de dígitos que satisfaz a expressão é três, por isso o resultado é `a123`.

---

Vale lembrar que o `?` também é um quantificador (que significa "zero ou uma ocorrência", que é outra forma de dizer que algo é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)), e portanto ele também pode ser *greedy* (ganancioso) ou *lazy* (preguiçoso):

```js
let s = 'a1234567890';

// sem lazy, pega a maior quantidade possível
console.log(s.match(/a\d?/)); // a1

// com lazy, pega a menor quantidade possível
console.log(s.match(/a\d??/)); // a
```

No primeiro caso, `\d?` indica que o dígito é opcional. Mas por *default*, todo quantificador é ganancioso, então ele tenta pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres (que nesse caso é 1), por isso no primeiro caso o retorno é `a1`.

Já no segundo caso, o quantificador `??` é preguiçoso (o primeiro `?` indica que o `\d` é opcional, e o segundo `?` torna o quantificador *lazy*) e pega a menor quantidade possível de caracteres, que no caso é zero. Por isso o retorno é `a`.

---

## Quando usar? Depende

É muito comum as pessoas usarem `.*?` sem nem parar para pensar se é isso mesmo que precisam, simplesmente porque é "mais fácil". Isso geralmente acontece porque elas primeiro tentam com `.*`, que gera os problemas apontados nas outras respostas: como o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere (*[exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), a menos [que se configure isso](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall)*), ele pode acabar pegando mais caracteres do que devia, caso a regex ache necessário. E aí acabam mudando para *lazy* e "pronto".

Usando o exemplo da [resposta do Pedro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308040/112052):

```js
let string = 'Eu quero pegar uma palavra que comece com "q" seguida por um espaço.';
console.log(string.match(/(q.*) /)[1]); // quero pegar uma palavra que comece com "q" seguida por um
console.log(string.match(/(q.*?) /)[1]); // quero
```

O objetivo era pegar uma palavra que começa com "q", seguido por um espaço. Mas como o `*` é ganancioso, por padrão ele tenta pegar o maior número possível de caracteres. E como o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere (inclusive o espaço), ele acaba pegando espaços a mais. Para evitar esse problema, usou-se o quantificador *lazy*, assim a regex não avança mais do que "deveria" e só pega até o primeiro espaço.

Mas nesse caso você não precisaria usar o ponto, e nem o quantificador *lazy*. Se você quer parar no primeiro espaço que tiver depois do "q", é melhor ser mais específico e [dizer exatamente o que você quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want). Nesse caso, você não quer "qualquer coisa", e sim "qualquer coisa que não seja um espaço". Sendo assim, a regex poderia ser:

```js
let string = 'Eu quero pegar uma palavra que comece com "q" seguida por um espaço.';
console.log(string.match(/(q[^ ]*) /)[1]); // quero
```

Eu usei a [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^ ]` (qualquer coisa que **não** seja espaço) - repare que há um espaço antes do `]`. Sendo assim, o quantificador nem precisa ser *lazy*, pois o `[^ ]*` já me garante que a regex só vai avançar até encontrar um espaço. Isso deixa não só a regex **mais clara quanto à sua intenção**, mas também mais eficiente: basta comparar [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/DF7TD6/2/debugger) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/jTl73B/2/debugger) a quantidade de passos que cada uma executa e ver que a opção com `[^ ]` precisa de menos passos que `.*?`.

Isso acontece porque, embora o quantificador *lazy* `.*?` funcione, ele [cobra o seu preço](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_expensive). Basicamente, depois de encontrar o primeiro `q` (na palavra "quero"), o `.*?` verifica se logo depois tem um espaço (ele é preguiçoso, então primeiro ele tenta com zero caracteres depois do `q`). Mas como logo depois não tem um espaço, a regex volta e o `.*?` encontra o `u`, e então verifica se o próximo caractere é um espaço. Como não é, ela volta e o `.*?` consome a letra `e`, e avança para ver se tem um espaço depois. Como não tem, ela volta e pega o `r`, e assim por diante, até encontrar o espaço. Todo esse vai e volta é chamado de *backtracking*, e é um processo custoso, dependendo da regex e das strings que ela está verificando. O ponto é que a regex sempre vai testar todas as possibilidades, até encontrar um *match* (ou até perceber que não há nenhum). E usando o ponto, as possibilidades aumentam ainda mais, já que ele corresponde a qualquer caractere.

Já usando `[^ ]` (ou qualquer outra expressão mais restritiva que o ponto), as coisas mudam: como o `[^ ]` foi usado com um quantificador *greedy*, o comportamento da regex é avançar de uma vez, o máximo de caracteres que puder - e no caso, ela avança até encontrar um espaço, que é justamente o que pretendíamos (e o melhor: **sem o *backtracking*** que ocorre com `.*?`). Ou seja, eu me aproveitei do comportamento ganancioso do quantificador para que a regex seja mais eficiente (se eu torná-lo *lazy* não haverá ganho algum, pois será feito *backtracking*, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/jTl73B/3/debugger)). Além disso, o fato de eu usar uma expressão mais específica (qualquer coisa que não seja espaço) em vez do ponto (que pode ser qualquer coisa), me garante que a regex não vai avançar mais do que devia.

**Obviamente** que, para strings pequenas ou regex que serão executadas poucas vezes, em situações nas quais o desempenho não é algo tão crítico, etc, a diferença não é tão grande assim, e de qualquer forma, se eficiência é um requisito importante, devem ser feitos testes para saber se a regex é de fato o gargalo. E a quantidade exata de passos executados pela regex pode variar conforme a situação, pois algumas linguagens e *engines* podem fazer certas otimizações dependendo da expressão e/ou das strings envolvidas (mas o *backtracking* causado por um quantificador *lazy* continua sendo um fator que piora o desempenho, independente disso).

De qualquer forma, ainda acho que é importante saber que o uso indiscriminado de `.*?` nem sempre é a melhor solução. Nem sempre você quer "qualquer coisa", muitas vezes você quer "qualquer coisa, desde que não seja X, Y ou Z".

Obs: ainda tem outra diferença. O ponto, por *default*, não considera as quebras de linha, mas `[^ ]` sim ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/qLZPDl/1/)). Se não quiser pegar as quebras de linha, pode trocar para `q\S*` (o atalho `\S` é tudo que não for espaço ou quebra de linha - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/qLZPDl/3/)), ou para algo mais específico como `q[a-z]*` ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/qLZPDl/4/)). Enfim, há várias opções para não precisar do quantificador *lazy*.

---

Outro caso em que o uso do quantificador *lazy* não é tão interessante é quando você quer pegar "tudo até o final da linha". Como o ponto, por padrão, não considera quebras de linha, eu poderia fazer:

```js
let string = "Vou pegar tudo depois do número 1: esse é o trecho que quero pegar, até o final da linha\nEsse trecho está em outra linha e não quero";
console.log(string.match(/\d: (.*)/)[1]); // esse é o trecho que quero pegar, até o final da linha
```

No caso, a regex tem `\d:` (um número seguido de `:` e espaço), e depois eu tenho `(.*)` (zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer coisa). Mas por *default* o ponto não considera as quebras de linha, então ele avança até encontrar o `\n`. Eu me aproveito do comportamento *greedy* para fazer a regex avançar até onde quero sem precisar fazer *backtracking* ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/O9hIcI/1/debugger) ela funcionando).

Mas se eu trocar a regex para `\d: (.*?)`, ela não pega o restante da linha (pois ele vai pegar a menor quantidade de caracteres, e nesse caso é zero, conforme os primeiros exemplos acima) - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/O9hIcI/4/). Neste caso eu teria que indicar que quero tudo até a quebra de linha, mudando a regex para `\d: (.*?)\n`, por exemplo. Mas aí o quantificador *lazy* fará o *backtracking* para verificar se já chegou ao final da linha, tornando a regex menos eficiente, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/O9hIcI/5/debugger).

Resumindo, nem sempre o quantificador *lazy* é a melhor solução (aliás, nem sempre ele é a solução).

---

Para os seus exemplos, o resultado é o mesmo porque você usou os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` (início e fim da string), então `^.*$` e `^.*?$` vão pegar "qualquer coisa do início ao fim da string", ou seja, tanto faz, pois sempre vai encontrar um *match* (a diferença é que `.*` vai dar *match* em strings vazias, enquanto `.+` exige que haja pelo menos um caractere). Mas ainda sim há uma diferença de desempenho, veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/ANw0vn/1/debugger), [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/ANw0vn/2/debugger), [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/ANw0vn/3/debugger) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/ANw0vn/4/debugger).

E sobre o uso indiscriminado de `.*?` e as consequências de forçar a regex a fazer muitos *backtrackings*, vale ler [este artigo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).