# Obter palavras entre aspas através de expressão regular

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

O código abaixo está me retornando este erro:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Código:

```
<?php
$matches = array(); 
# Executa expressao
$string1 = 'string(10) "CURITIBA" string(11) "SP"'; 
$pattern = '/""(.*)""/'; 
preg_match($pattern , $string1, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
?>
```

Eu queria que meu echo me retornasse assim:

```
Curitiba
SP
```

Comment: Isso está acontecendo porque o seu `$pattern` está incorreto. Vamos esperar a galera que manja de expressões regulares te ajudar com essa questão.

Comment: ok, n entendo mt de expressão regular, aguardando :)

Comment: O ideal seria você editar a pergunta para algo do tipo "Obter palavras entre aspas através de expressão regular". Pois o alerta `Notice: Undefined offset: 1` se dá ao fato que o array `$matches` não possui o índice `1`.

Comment: obrigado pela dica, vou alterar!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É porque sua regex não está encontrando nada na string. Não existe nenhuma ocorrência na string entre um par de aspas duplas. Os nomes que você quer estão entre duas aspas apenas. Mas também você deveria usar `preg_match_all()` para encontrar todas as ocorrências, porque o `preg_match()` só vai encontrar uma.

E na regex você deverá usar o caractere `?` (lazy) após o `*` para retornar apenas a string dentro das aspas, senão irá buscar da primeira aspas até a última ([pergunta sobre o lazy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/308036/8063)). Ficaria:

```
$pattern = '/"(.*?)"/';
```

Irá retornar um subarray com as duas informações, uma em cada índice do índice 1 (grupo 1) da array principal:

```
echo $matches[1][0];  // CURITIBA
echo $matches[1][1];  // SP
```

**[Veja no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/ZuM6hG)**

Não precisa criar a array nesta linha: `$matches = array();`, porque o `$matches` na função `preg_match_all` já irá retornar uma array.

Comment: Sam, você poderia explicar o que seria cada caractere do regex ou apontar um conteúdo de qualidade para estudar essas expressões. Obrigado!

Comment: Certo, muito bom amigo, agradeço seu comentário, me ajudo muito!

Comment: Oi @VictorCarnaval. Cara, acho que não seja necessário neste caso explicar cada caractere da regex. Como ela já tinha a regex pronta, faltando apenas o `?`, eu apenas coloquei um link pra uma pergunta que fiz sobre o caractere, e lá tem tudo explicadinho nas respostas.

Comment: @VictorCarnaval Se tivesse que criar uma nova regex diferente, aí sim seria necessário explicar o que ela faz com detalhes.

Comment: Vou ler a sua pergunta, obrigado!

Comment: @VictorCarnaval Sobre material de estudo, dois sites que gosto bastante (e que sempre cito nas respostas) são [esse](https://www.regular-expressions.info) e [esse](http://rexegg.com). E se quiser ir fundo mesmo no assunto, tem esse livro: https://www.amazon.com/dp/0596528124/

Comment: Obrigado pelo conteúdo @hkotsubo.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementando, uma alternativa é:

```
$string1 = 'string(10) "CURITIBA" string(11) "SP"';
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $string1, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $m) {
    echo $m.PHP_EOL;
}
```

A diferença para a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401123/112052) é que a regex é `"([^"]+)"`:

- no início e fim temos as aspas
- no meio temos `[^"]`, que é uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). Basicamente, ela significa qualquer caractere que **não** seja o `"`
- o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ele é diferente do `*`, que significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, se usar `*`, a regex também considera os casos em que não há nada entre as aspas. Usando `+`, eu só pego os casos em que há pelo menos um caractere entre elas (veja a diferença [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/PJJEc9/1/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/fbrUMH/1/)). Use o que fizer mais sentido para você.
- [os parênteses servem para formar um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim o array de *matches* terá uma posição para guardar os trechos que correspondem aos parênteses (no caso, é `$matches[1]`, pois como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então é o primeiro grupo de captura, que fica no índice 1)

O resultado é:

```
CURITIBA
SP
```

A outra diferença é que `[^"]+` é um pouco mais eficiente que `.*?`. Isso acontece porque o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere (qualquer um, inclusive as aspas, por isso é necessário o `?` para que o quantificador `*` [não pegue mais caracteres do que deveria](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) - veja a diferença [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/PJJEc9/2/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/PJJEc9/3/)). E como ele pode pegar qualquer caractere, inclusive as aspas caso ache necessário, a regex acaba testando possibilidades demais, até encontrar os *matches* (o quantificador *lazy* - como é chamado o `*?` - é bem útil, [mas cobra o seu preço](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_expensive)).

Já usando `[^"]+`, a regex pode avançar sem medo, pois ela não corresponde mais a qualquer caractere, e sim qualquer caractere que não seja o `"`. Ou seja, isso garante que a regex vai parar quando encontrar um `"`. Isso torna ela mais eficiente, basta comparar a quantidade de passos [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/cXBR9Q/1/debugger) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/umB7o0/1/debugger).

**Obviamente**, para strings pequenas e poucas execuções, não faz tanta diferença assim (talvez o ganho seja de milissegundos ou até menos). Mas para strings maiores, ou para processamentos em que a regex rodará muitas vezes, aí começa a fazer diferença (compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/cXBR9Q/3/debugger) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/umB7o0/3/debugger) - e repare que a maior diferença é nos casos em que a regex falha porque as aspas não fecham, pois o ponto gera muito mais possibilidades a serem testadas - e a regex testa **todas** até encontrar um *match*, ou até perceber que não há nenhum).

Outra diferença é que por *default* o ponto pega qualquer caractere, [exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). Já `[^"]` considera as quebras de linha. Então se tivermos uma string contendo uma quebra de linha entre as aspas, somente a segunda encontra um *match* - compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/cXBR9Q/4/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/umB7o0/4/). (mas neste caso, bastaria usar a [*flag*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `s` na regex: `'/"(.+?)"/s'` - pois assim o ponto também considera as quebras de linha).

---

Se quiser ser mais específico ainda, pode usar algo como:

```
preg_match_all('/"([A-Z]+)"/', $string1, $matches);
```

Agora a regex só vai pegar os casos em que houver letras maiúsculas entre as aspas (`[A-Z]+` é "uma ou mais letras de `A` a `Z`"). Isso faria diferença se você tivesse casos como `"123"` e quisesse ignorá-los, por exemplo.

Usar `.*` parece ser mais fácil, mas nem sempre você quer "qualquer coisa". Muitas vezes você tem um conjunto bem definido de caracteres que quer considerar (ou ignorar), e geralmente [é melhor que a expressão diga exatamente o que você quer e o que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want).

---

Obs: a sua regex tinha duas aspas no início e duas no fim, por isso não encontrava nada.