# Grupo opcional não está sendo capturado

Tags: regex, notepad++

Tenho um enorme arquivo de registros que eu quero transformar em uma tabela. O arquivo se parece com isto:

```
********************
SemprePresente1=09/2019
SemprePresente2=987456
Um monte de coisas  
Que não preciso
Opcional=698,00
Mais coisas que não preciso
********************
SemprePresente1=06/2019
SemprePresente2=123658
Um monte de coisas 
Que não preciso
********************
SemprePresente1=09/2019
SemprePresente2=987699
Um monte de coisas
Opcional=9999,00
Mais coisas que não preciso
```

Eu consigo capturar os dois primeiros grupos, mas não o terceiro, que é opcional, usando a seguinte regex:

```
^[\*].+?SemprePresente1=(\d\d\/\d\d\d\d).+?SemprePresente2=(\d{6}).+?((:?Opcional=)[\d,]+)?[^\*]+
```

Eu preciso de algo assim:

```
09/2019;987456;698,00
06/2019;123658;
09/2019;987699;9999,00
```

Entretanto, usando o padrão de substituição `\1;\2;\4\n` no Notepad++ eu só consigo isto:

```
09/2019;987456;
06/2019;123658;
09/2019;987699;
```

Por que não estou conseguindo capturar o grupo opcional? Aparentemente, o padrão está combinando com o registro inteiro, sem "invadir" o próximo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar esta regex:

```
^[\*].+?SemprePresente1=(\d{2}\/\d{4}).+?SemprePresente2=(\d{6})(?:(?!Opcional=)[^\*])+(Opcional=(\d+,\d+))?[^\*]+
```

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/LYKPrO/1/) ela funcionando no regex101.com.

---

Fiz algumas alterações na sua regex. Basicamente, usei os [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{2}` e `{4}`, que são respectivamente, "2 ocorrências" e "4 ocorrências". Ou seja, `\d{4}` é o mesmo que `\d\d\d\d`.

Outro detalhe é que `:?` quer dizer que o caractere `:` é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), ou seja, pode ou não ter o caractere `:` na string. Acho que você tentou na verdade usar `(?:` para criar um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap).

De qualquer forma, a regex não funciona porque o grupo opcional (contendo a string "Opcional") era pulado. Primeiro a regex cai no `.+?` logo depois do trecho "SemprePresente2", e como esse quantificador é ["preguiçoso"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution), ele tenta pegar a menor quantidade possível de caracteres. Ou seja, a regex ainda não "andou" caracteres o suficiente para chegar no "Opcional" (pois ela está logo depois do número correspondente a "SemprePresente2"), mas já tenta verificar esse trecho nesta posição da string.

Mas como esse trecho é opcional, a regex tenta verificar primeiro se **não** tem essa parte, e só depois, se não der certo, ela volta e tenta ver se essa parte opcional existe. Então primeiro ela pula esse grupo e verifica a expressão que vem depois.

E depois do grupo "Opcional" temos `[^\*]+`, e por padrão os quantificadores são ["gananciosos"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e tentam pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres. No caso, ele pega vários caracteres que não são `*`, ou seja, ele avança até encontrar um `*`, e não volta mais para verificar o grupo opcional.

Você pode ver esse comportamento [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/DE7aFo/3/debugger): use as setas do teclado para acompanhar os passos que a regex faz (veja a partir do passo 68 do primeiro *match*).

---

A solução foi, antes do grupo opcional, usar um [*lookahead negativo*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (o trecho entre `(?!...)`), que verifica se algo **não** existe à frente. O "truque" do *lookahead* é que ele só vê o que está na frente, e depois volta para onde estava e continua verificando a regex.

No caso, o trecho é `(?:(?!Opcional=)[^\*])+`, ou seja, primeiro eu vejo se **não** tem o trecho "Opcional=" à frente, e depois eu verifico se o caractere seguinte não é `*`. E faço isso várias vezes (graças ao quantificador `+`). Isso garante que o grupo opcional só será verificado quando realmente tivemos certeza que ele existe (ou, caso não exista, a regex acaba chegando em um `*` e encerra).

Depois do *lookahead*, temos o trecho `Opcional=(\d+,\d+)`, que pega o número que você precisa. Repare que mudei a expressão também, pois você estava usando `[\d,]+`, que apesar de funcionar, também pode pegar coisas inválidas como `,,,,` e `2,2,3,4` ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/AIvcdD/1/)).

Fazendo a substituição por `\1;\2;\4\n` no Notepad++, obtive:

```
09/2019;987456;698,00
06/2019;123658;
09/2019;987699;9999,00
```

---

Para mais detalhes sobre os quantificadores "preguiçosos" e "gananciosos", veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052).

Lembrando também que, por padrão, [o ponto não considera as quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), então você deve [habilitar esta opção no Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13934667), para que sua regex funcione (já que ela usa `.+` para pegar trechos entre linhas diferentes).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Não só resolveu meu problema, como a explicação detalhada me ajudou a entender o que estava fazendo errado.